# Summary time for Splay-tree

Tags: algorithm, math

Consider a splay-tree containing numbers from `1...n`. Then we address `m` requests to the vertices `x_1, x_2, ..., x_m`. It is known that `|x_i - x_{i-1}| > d` . We need to find summary working time of there requests.

I think that the answer would be `O(m*log(d))`, but not sure how to prove...